# gitlab-ci.yml - variables not evaluated

Tags: gitlab-ci

My gitlab-ci.yml is configured to deploy to a staging server on push to a staging branch.  Each developer has their own staging server for testing.  The way I have it now doesn't seem very scalable, in that I would have to duplicate each job for each user.

I have now:

```
deploy_to_staging_sf:
  image: debian:jessie
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - staging_sf
  tags:
    - staging_sf
  script:
    - ./deploy.sh

deploy_to_staging_ay:
  image: debian:jessie
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - staging_ay
  tags:
    - staging_ay
  script:
    - ./deploy.sh
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do some kind of regex or pattern matching to keep it DRY and scalable, and I came up with this...

```
deploy_to_staging:
  image: debian:jessie
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - /^staging_.*$/
  tags:
    - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  script:
    - ./deploy.sh
```

I have the tag for the runner configured to match the branch name. However, `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` is not evaluated for `tags`, and I just get the error

```
This job is stuck, because you don't have any active runners online
with any of these tags assigned to them: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
```

Is this actually possible and have I just done something wrong, or is just not possible to evaluate variables here at all?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like it's an open issue with GitLab:  

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18758  
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20615  
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24207